# Loop through a table's td's and check content on inner spans then change the color of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I loop through this table and check all the spans with a class of code and if they contain Failed to send invite then color the text Failed to send invite to red?

```
 <table>
 <tr height="20" class="oddListRowS1">
     <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot73b" class="code">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" onclick="" value="28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a" id="Contactscheckbox_display_id[]" class="checkbox" name="Contactscheckbox_display[]"></span></td>

     <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot74b" class="code"><a href="?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DContacts%26action%3DDetailView%26record%3D28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a">Gabriel Litchfield</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot75b" class="code"><a href="?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DAccounts%26action%3DDetailView%26record%3D95678448-0ddd-eb6e-2fc1-516bdc8f7eff">P Piper &amp; Sons</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot76b" class="code">(166) 682-8040</span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot77b" class="code"><a onclick="SUGAR.quickCompose.init({&quot;fullComposeUrl&quot;:&quot;load_id=28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a\u0026load_module=Delegates\u0026parent_type=Delegates\u0026parent_id=28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a\u0026return_module=FP_events\u0026return_action=DetailView\u0026return_id=8dd846fd-e6d3-f6ae-a155-51b700a61700\u0026parent_name=Gabriel+Litchfield\u0026to_email_addrs=Gabriel+Litchfield+%3Chr.beans%40example.us%3E&quot;,&quot;composePackage&quot;:{&quot;load_id&quot;:&quot;28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a&quot;,&quot;load_module&quot;:&quot;Delegates&quot;,&quot;parent_type&quot;:&quot;Delegates&quot;,&quot;parent_id&quot;:&quot;28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a&quot;,&quot;return_module&quot;:&quot;FP_events&quot;,&quot;return_action&quot;:&quot;DetailView&quot;,&quot;return_id&quot;:&quot;8dd846fd-e6d3-f6ae-a155-51b700a61700&quot;,&quot;parent_name&quot;:&quot;Gabriel Litchfield&quot;,&quot;to_email_addrs&quot;:&quot;Gabriel Litchfield \u003Chr.beans@example.us\u003E&quot;}});" href="javascript:void(0);">hr.beans@example.us</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot78b" class="code">Invited has been sent</span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot79b" class="code">No Responce</span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="inlineButtons" scope="row"><span sugar="slot80b" class="code"><ul name="" class="clickMenu subpanel records fancymenu button SugarActionMenu" id="ab583b12-7612-20a0-6ef1-51e92fffd078"><li class="sugar_action_button"><div id="ab583b12-7612-20a0-6ef1-51e92fffd078" style="display: inline"><a id="delegates_edit_9" class="listViewTdToolsS1" onfocus="javascript:subp_nav('Contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 'e', this, 'fp_events_contacts');" onmouseover="javascript:subp_nav('Contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 'e', this, 'fp_events_contacts');" href="#">edit</a></div><ul class="subnav" id=""><li><a onclick="return sp_rem_conf();" id="delegates_remove_9" class="listViewTdToolsS1" href="javascript:sub_p_rem('delegates', 'fp_events_contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 0);">remove</a></li></ul><span class="ab"></span></li></ul></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="20" class="oddListRowS1">
     <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot73b" class="code">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" onclick="" value="28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a" id="Contactscheckbox_display_id[]" class="checkbox" name="Contactscheckbox_display[]"></span></td>

     <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot74b" class="code"><a href="?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DContacts%26action%3DDetailView%26record%3D28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a">Gabriel Litchfield</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot75b" class="code"><a href="?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DAccounts%26action%3DDetailView%26record%3D95678448-0ddd-eb6e-2fc1-516bdc8f7eff">P Piper &amp; Sons</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot76b" class="code">(166) 682-8040</span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot77b" class="code"><a onclick="SUGAR.quickCompose.init({&quot;fullComposeUrl&quot;:&quot;load_id=28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a\u0026load_module=Delegates\u0026parent_type=Delegates\u0026parent_id=28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a\u0026return_module=FP_events\u0026return_action=DetailView\u0026return_id=8dd846fd-e6d3-f6ae-a155-51b700a61700\u0026parent_name=Gabriel+Litchfield\u0026to_email_addrs=Gabriel+Litchfield+%3Chr.beans%40example.us%3E&quot;,&quot;composePackage&quot;:{&quot;load_id&quot;:&quot;28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a&quot;,&quot;load_module&quot;:&quot;Delegates&quot;,&quot;parent_type&quot;:&quot;Delegates&quot;,&quot;parent_id&quot;:&quot;28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a&quot;,&quot;return_module&quot;:&quot;FP_events&quot;,&quot;return_action&quot;:&quot;DetailView&quot;,&quot;return_id&quot;:&quot;8dd846fd-e6d3-f6ae-a155-51b700a61700&quot;,&quot;parent_name&quot;:&quot;Gabriel Litchfield&quot;,&quot;to_email_addrs&quot;:&quot;Gabriel Litchfield \u003Chr.beans@example.us\u003E&quot;}});" href="javascript:void(0);">hr.beans@example.us</a></span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot78b" class="code">Invited has been sent</span></td>

      <td valign="top" class="" scope="row"><span sugar="slot79b" class="code">No Responce</span></td>

      <td class="" valign="top" scope="row">
          <span class="code" sugar="slot51b"> Invited has been sent</span>
      </td>

      <td valign="top" class="inlineButtons" scope="row"><span sugar="slot80b" class="code"><ul name="" class="clickMenu subpanel records fancymenu button SugarActionMenu" id="ab583b12-7612-20a0-6ef1-51e92fffd078"><li class="sugar_action_button"><div id="ab583b12-7612-20a0-6ef1-51e92fffd078" style="display: inline"><a id="delegates_edit_9" class="listViewTdToolsS1" onfocus="javascript:subp_nav('Contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 'e', this, 'fp_events_contacts');" onmouseover="javascript:subp_nav('Contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 'e', this, 'fp_events_contacts');" href="#">edit</a></div><ul class="subnav" id=""><li><a onclick="return sp_rem_conf();" id="delegates_remove_9" class="listViewTdToolsS1" href="javascript:sub_p_rem('delegates', 'fp_events_contacts', '28f6634e-b7bd-3654-7cc5-516bdddb573a', 0);">remove</a></li></ul><span class="ab"></span></li></ul></span></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're not just outputting an additional css class for those rows when you generate the HTML?

Comment: I cant change any of the html and ignor oddListRowS1

Comment: *Why* can't you change the HTML? Is this a question for a class, or for production code?

Comment: its for a production, I dont control the html just trying to add a bit of JavaScript$('td span.code').each(function() {
   var span = $(this);
   if (span.text() == 'Failed to send invite') {
       span.css('color', 'red');
   } 
}); to something that is existings

Comment: Please post the jquery code that you've tried. You've only given us one piece to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$('table span.code').each( function() {
  if( /(Failed to send invite)/.test($(this).html() ) ) {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
  }
})
```

Comment: I cant change where the checking class is, it has to be on the span inside the td and oddListRowS1 is irrelevant so I cant use that in the jquery code.

Comment: This one ended up being the only one I could get working off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td span.code').each(function() {
   var span = $(this);
   if (span.text() == 'Failed to send invite') {
       span.css('color', 'red');
   } 
});
```

HTML

```
<span class="code">Failed to send invite</span>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Gwb7C/)**

Comment: Make sure you have something like this in your markup `<span class="code">Failed to send invite</span>`, answer updated

Comment: This was closest to how I probably would Have ended up doing it.